# Battery percentage code returns o when charging

Tags: android, battery

I used the below code to get the battery percentage in my app. This code returns the battery percentage when not connected to charging. **But when it is charging it returns zero**

How can I make this code work even on charging?

```
public int getBatteryPercentage()
{
    BroadcastReceiver batteryLevelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
            int currentLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
            level = -1;
            if (currentLevel >= 0 && scale > 0) {
                level = (currentLevel * 100) / scale;
            }
        }
    };  
    IntentFilter batteryLevelFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
    registerReceiver(batteryLevelReceiver, batteryLevelFilter);
    return level;
}
```

Comment: try this --- int currentLevel = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);

Comment: @Shrinithi how would a default level of zero solve this problem?

Comment: Shrinithi its still returning 0

Answer (score 1):

This what am using its working fine for me

```
 int level = 0;
 level_new = i.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
    scale = i.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

    if (level_new >= 0 && scale > 0) {
        level = (level_new * 100) / scale;
    } else {
        level = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Application works fine if its not on charging.. But on charging or debugging it returns zero